# Performance issues when displaying data very frequently

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have high CPU utilization when receive large amount of data through the TCP. Amount of data that I receive is ~500 objects per second. If I don't use Task.Delay() UI starts lagging and CPU utilization is 40%. If I add some delay, then everything starts working normal (CPU utilization is 3-7%), but frequency of data updates on the View is dropping slightly (around 75%). Is this a limitation of the WPF application - it can't display data so frequently?

Comment: I'd say you want to batch those operations - are we talking 500 updates per second on a view in WPF? If so that's probably overdoing it, the average professional CSGO player uses a 144hz monitor which is enough for them to get flick headshots with the AWP... just sayin!

Comment: Yes, you can't punish the UI thread and expect it to not result in an unresponsive UI that takes up a lot of CPU. You should record your fast data on a different thread and update the UI using a DispatcherTimer which does the update at a scheduled interval (like twice a second or whatever).

Comment: WPF is weak in displaying of large data in real time. You will need to go DirectX / GDI+ / you name it if you want a great performance with lower CPU usage.

Comment: When used properly you can also use CompositionTarget.Rendering to your advantage (although it can, and does, get called multiple times per render frame so you need to check for that).